# Chartjs. barras con condicional propia

Tags: condiciones, chart.js

Buen día , antes que nada le agradezco aquien pueda ayudarme, soy nuevo en esto y estoy creando un gráfico con chart.js necesito que cada barra cambie de color de acuerdo a condicionales diferentes, por ejemplo para a debe ser verde si el valor se encuentra entre 0 -15, naranja entre 16 y 30. mientras que para b verde 0 - 10, naranja de 11-20, espero puedan ayudarme.

```
var chartColors = {
  color1: 'rgba(132, 228, 57, 0.7)',
  color2: 'rgba(197, 228, 51, 0.9)',
  color3: 'rgba(251, 251, 0, 0.9)',
  color4: 'rgba(218, 117, 57, 0.5)',
  color5: 'rgba(218, 57, 57, 0.5)'
};

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Categorías"],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'a',
       backgroundColor: [
        chartColors.color1,
        chartColors.color1,
        chartColors.color1,
        chartColors.color1,
        chartColors.color1
      ],
      data: [29]
    },{

      label: "b",

      data: [31],
      backgroundColor: [
       chartColors.color1
     ],
   },{

      label: "c",

      data: [41],
      backgroundColor: [
       chartColors.color1
     ],
   },{

     label: "d",

     data: [30],
     backgroundColor: [
      chartColors.color1
    ],
  },{

    label: "e",

    data: [61],
    backgroundColor: [
     chartColors.color1
   ],
 }
  ],
  }
});




 var colorChangeValue = 50; //set this to whatever is the deciding color change value
    var dataset = myChart.data.datasets[0];
    for (var i = 0; i < dataset.data.length; i++) {
      if (dataset.data[i] < 30) {
        dataset.backgroundColor[i] = chartColors.color1;
      }
      else if ((dataset.data[i] > 31) && (dataset.data[i] <= 39)){
        dataset.backgroundColor[i] = chartColors.color2;
      }
      else if ((dataset.data[i] > 40) && (dataset.data[i] <= 50)){
        dataset.backgroundColor[i] = chartColors.color3;
      }
      else if ((dataset.data[i] > 51) && (dataset.data[i] <= 60)){
        dataset.backgroundColor[i] = chartColors.color4;
      }
      else{
       dataset.backgroundColor[i] = chartColors.color5;
      }
    }
    myChart.update();
```

Desconozco si es la forma correcta ya que no se como crear o asilar cada barra para aplicar la condicional requerida a cada una de estas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas accesando al dataset incorrecto.  Necesitas accesar a `myChart.data.datasets` asi:

```js
var chartColors = {
  color1: 'rgba(132, 228, 57, 0.7)',
  color2: 'rgba(197, 228, 51, 0.9)',
  color3: 'rgba(251, 251, 0, 0.9)',
  color4: 'rgba(218, 117, 57, 0.5)',
  color5: 'rgba(218, 57, 57, 0.5)'
};

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Categorías"],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'a',
       backgroundColor: [
        chartColors.color1,
        chartColors.color1,
        chartColors.color1,
        chartColors.color1,
        chartColors.color1
      ],
      data: [29]
    },{

      label: "b",

      data: [31],
      backgroundColor: [
       chartColors.color1
     ],
   },{

      label: "c",

      data: [41],
      backgroundColor: [
       chartColors.color1
     ],
   },{

     label: "d",

     data: [30],
     backgroundColor: [
      chartColors.color1
    ],
  },{

    label: "e",

    data: [61],
    backgroundColor: [
     chartColors.color1
   ],
 }
  ],
  }
});

 var colorChangeValue = 50; //set this to whatever is the deciding color change value
    var dataset = myChart.data.datasets;
    for (var i = 0; i < dataset.length; i++) {
      if (dataset[i].data <= 30) {
        dataset[i].backgroundColor = chartColors.color1;
      }
      else if ((dataset[i].data >= 31) && (dataset[i].data <= 39)){
        dataset[i].backgroundColor = chartColors.color2;
      }
      else if ((dataset[i].data > 40) && (dataset[i].data <= 50)){
        dataset[i].backgroundColor = chartColors.color3;
      }
      else if ((dataset[i].data > 51) && (dataset[i].data <= 60)){
        dataset[i].backgroundColor = chartColors.color4;
      }
      else{
       dataset[i].backgroundColor = chartColors.color5;
      }
    }
    myChart.update();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.css"/>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

Comment: Wooaw ,muchas gracias lo resolviste super rapido, jeje llevo mas de dos días y no encontraba la solución, ahora solo intentare ingresar los valores desde una base de php deseame y como te comnetaba estoy empezando en esto, hay alguna forma de darte like, puntos o contribuir en algo?.

Comment: Ya lo hiciste, ya seleccionaste la respuesta como correcta.  Tambien puedes votar a favor.

Comment: Ok otra duda como puedo encasillar varias condicionales para cada una de las barras?, es que quiero poder cinco if anidados con diferentes valores para cada barra.

Answer (score 0):

quedaria algo asi...

```
var a = 5;
var b = 5;
var colora = "";

if(a<=15){
  colora = "rgba(255,0,0,1)";
}else{
  colora = "rgba(255,200,0,1)";
}

if(b<=10){
   colorb = "rgba(255,0,0,1)";
   }else{
     colorb = "rgba(255,200,0,1)"
   }

var chartColors = {
  color1: colora,
  color2: colorb,
};

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Categorías"],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'a',
       backgroundColor: [
        colora,
      ],
      data: [a]
    },{

      label: "b",

      data: [b],
      backgroundColor: [
       colorb
     ],
   },
  ],
  }
});
```

simplementa se hace una validacion con los rangos, y ya con esto puedes verificar que color tendrá

Comment: Muchas gracias, en si terminé oprtando por usarlo en canvas ya que baje un codigo de am4charts pero no logré modificarlo apenas toco algo y truena, conoces esos samples?

Comment: no, no los conozco pero igual tratare de ayudarte.